# Unity - "incorrect path for a scene file"

Tags: unity3d

У меня ошибка в Unity `2020.3.1f1`, когда я сохраняю Unity в обличье <.exe>.

- Первая ошибка:

```
'' is an incorrect path for a scene file. BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.
```

- Вторая ошибка:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 9 seconds (8817 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

- Третья ошибка:

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: '' is an incorrect path for a scene file. BuildPlayer expects paths relative to the project folder.
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <0c3742f371b24679bcaa6fcc508d0cca>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <0c3742f371b24679bcaa6fcc508d0cca>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: попробуй перезакинуть сцену в Build Settings и скажи, нет ли русских папок в проекте или чего либо

Comment: плюс посмотри нет ли там пустышки

Comment: а вообще можешь скриншот просто сделать и сказать что ты делал с SampleScene в папке Scenes